# Unique id for each Firefox & Chrome extension installation

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, browser-extension

Is there a way to generate something like a "computer id" that will be different on each computer on from a firefor and chrome extension to use for tracking purposes?

I mean, I want each extension installation to have a unique id that will be always the same on that computer, but different on each computer.

*The id doesn't need to be the same on both chrome and firefox extension*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I end up just generating a random guid with js and storing it as a normal preference the first time the extension runs.

Comment: It's proper way. BTW I'm looking for some of browser's instance/installation read-only id to use as part of propertiary addon's distribution securing. Any idea?